# Mutate operation by group in a FOR loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a beginner in R and I'm facing an issue while calculating row differences by group for multiple columns.

What I wrote up till now:

```
dt2 <- function(dataset){
  s_list <- c("S17", "S1", "S3", "S5", "S7")
  for (val in s_list){
    dt2_df <- dataset %>%
    group_by(order) %>%
    mutate(noquote(val) - lag(noquote(val)))
    dt2_df$s_list[val] <- NULL
  }
 return(dt2_df)
}
```

The s_list is basically the column names of my dataset (for which I need row differences). If I'm doing it separately for each column then I'm getting the right answer (but the code is awfully long - using the mutate function repeatedly).

What I need: A dataframe which only contains the row wise differences for each column mentioned in the s_list and the groupid (order)

What is wrong with the above code: I get the error below:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `..1` is `noquote(val) - lag(noquote(val))`.
i The error occured in group 1: order = 4779830.
```

Additional information: The values of each column in s_list contains timestamp information and "NA"(for no observation).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

What does work:

```
delta2_df <- df %>%
  group_by(order) %>%
  mutate(S17 - lag(S17)) %>%
  mutate(S1 - lag(S1)) %>%
  mutate(S3 - lag(S3)) %>%
  mutate(S5 - lag(S5)) %>%
  mutate(S7 - lag(S7))
```

But this will get awfully long because I have 18 columns. (The s_list only shows the first 5).

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a dput(head(df)) so that we can see what format "S17", "S1", "S3", "S5", "S7" are in

Comment: The dataset that you assumed below is correct. I couldn't post it because majority of values are NA. Apologies. But the solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a function or anything fancy since you already are using `dplyr` I'm assuming what your data looks like but this should do it.  (I'm using the older `mutate_at` rather than `across` because I don't want to assume you have the latest version of `dplyr`.  FWIW the specific error message you generated with your function is because `noquote` is really only helpful for printing, it doesn't actually modify the string "S17" to make it the variable name you need.

```r
library(dplyr)
# Your expected outcome
# df %>%
# #  group_by(order) %>%
#   mutate(S17 - lag(S17)) %>%
#   mutate(S1 - lag(S1)) %>%
#   mutate(S3 - lag(S3)) %>%
#   mutate(S5 - lag(S5)) %>%
#   mutate(S7 - lag(S7))

delta2_df <- 
   df %>% 
   mutate_at(c("S17", "S1", "S3", "S5", "S7"), list(lagged = ~ . - lag(.)))

delta2_df %>%
   select(ends_with("_lagged")) %>%
   slice_head(n = 5)
#>        S17_lagged       S1_lagged     S3_lagged      S5_lagged      S7_lagged
#> 1         NA secs         NA secs       NA secs        NA secs        NA secs
#> 2   3.459238 secs 35.5398948 secs 38.31058 secs  7.582288 secs  4.819725 secs
#> 3   1.562570 secs  9.0936852 secs 44.25048 secs 41.544859 secs  5.264784 secs
#> 4  30.447722 secs  0.2308176 secs 50.53320 secs  4.032063 secs 63.913645 secs
#> 5 165.459635 secs  2.2446895 secs 13.80334 secs  7.527049 secs 21.084198 secs
```

Based on this data...

```r
    set.seed(2020)
    df <- data.frame(
      S17 = sort(as.POSIXct(" 2020-07-08 07:00:00") + runif(n=100, min=0, max=3600)),
      S1 = sort(as.POSIXct(" 2020-07-08 08:00:00") + runif(n=100, min=0, max=3600)),
      S3 = sort(as.POSIXct(" 2020-07-08 09:00:00") + runif(n=100, min=0, max=3600)),
      S5 = sort(as.POSIXct(" 2020-07-08 10:00:00") + runif(n=100, min=0, max=3600)),
      S7 = sort(as.POSIXct(" 2020-07-08 11:00:00") + runif(n=100, min=0, max=3600))
    )
```